# How do i access input channels above 2 with python pyaudio or sounddevice?

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, audio-processing

I have built audio recorders in python with both pyaudio and sounddevice.  I can successfully record audio input and write it to a .wav file.

I am now trying to access other channels on my audio interface.  No where in documentation, forums, etc.. can I find how to record an interfaces channel 3,4,5,6, etc..., I can only seem to record channel 1.  Here i my existing code, can someone point me in the right direction?

Sounddevice:

`recording = sounddevice.rec(int(duration*samplerate), samplerate=samplerate, channels=1, device=device_info["name"]);`

`sounddevice.wait();`

Pyaudio:

`stream = audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=frame_rate, input=True, frames_per_buffer=frame_per_buffer, input_device_index=input_index);`

**Additional Details**

Here are my audio inputs

```
ACTIVE DEVICES:
  0 BlackHole 16ch, Core Audio (16 in, 16 out)
> 1 MacBook Pro Microphone, Core Audio (1 in, 0 out)
< 2 MacBook Pro Speakers, Core Audio (0 in, 2 out)
  3 eqMac, Core Audio (2 in, 2 out)
  4 MicChannel3, Core Audio (3 in, 4 out)
```

When i select device 1, and input channel 1, i get sound! I set up 4 as a Mac Aggregate Device, where input 3 = Macbook Pro Microphone, and the first 2 inputs are empty. When i select device 4, input channel 3, i get no sound in my audio file.  I think the "Channel" parameter for both libraries is mono vs stereo, not which channel to record.

Comment: channels = N where N is 3,4,5,6,etc...

Comment: Thanks for the response, but doing any channel besides "1" is not working for me, ill add details above about what i tested.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that your current active device (1 MacBook Pro Microphone, Core Audio (1 in, 0 out) ) supports only one input channel.

For example in my case if I select as input device the ( 7 Clarett 2Pre USB: Audio (hw:1,0), ALSA (12 in, 4 out) ) from the list below, then I can specify at most 12 input channels.

```
0 HDA Intel PCH: ALC887-VD Analog (hw:0,0), ALSA (2 in, 2 out)
   1 HDA Intel PCH: ALC887-VD Alt Analog (hw:0,2), ALSA (2 in, 0 out)
   2 HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 0 (hw:0,3), ALSA (0 in, 2 out)
   3 HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 1 (hw:0,7), ALSA (0 in, 8 out)
   4 HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 2 (hw:0,8), ALSA (0 in, 8 out)
   5 HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 3 (hw:0,9), ALSA (0 in, 8 out)
   6 HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 4 (hw:0,10), ALSA (0 in, 8 out)
   7 Clarett 2Pre USB: Audio (hw:1,0), ALSA (12 in, 4 out)
```

You have to select another device or add an audio interface to your computer.